# Angular - How to either export to excel or just use search filter query based on selected action

Tags: angular, excel, asp.net-core

In Angular-15 application, I am consuming an endpoint from ASP.NET Core Web API that filter, sort search, paginate and export data to excel based on the choice as shown in this backend Controller:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route(ApiRoutesGetAllMandates)]
public async Task<ActionResult> GetAllMandateAsync([FromQuery] PagingFilter filter, [FromQuery] bool exportToExcel = false)
{
    if (exportToExcel)
    {
        var response = await _adminMandatesService.ExportAllMandateToExcelAsync(filter);

        if (response.Successful)
        {
            var fileBytes = response.Data;
            var fileName = $"MandateReports_{DateTime.Now:yyyyMMddHHmmss}.xlsx";

            return File(fileBytes, "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet", fileName);
        }
        else
        {
            return StatusCode(response.StatusCode, response.Message);
        }
    }
    var result = await _adminMandatesService.GetAllMandateAsync(filter);
    return StatusCode(result.StatusCode, result);
}
```

Now this is the Angular code:

Interface:

```
export interface AdminMandateListDto {
  id: string;
  merchantId: string;
  // Add more properties as per your requirements
}

export interface PagingFilter {
  pageNumber: number;
  pageSize: number;
  searchQuery: string;
  sortBy: string;
  isSortAscending: boolean;
  startDate: Date | null;
  endDate: Date | null;
}

export interface PageResult<T> {
  pageItems: T;
  currentPage: number;
  pageSize: number;
  numberOfPages: number;
  totalRecord: number;
}

export interface Response<T> {
  data: T;
  successful: boolean;
  message: string;
  statusCode: number;
  responseCode: string;
  responseDescription: string;
}
```

Service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpParams } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

import { AdminMandateListDto, PagingFilter, PageResult, Response } from './models'; // Import necessary models

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AdminMandateService {
  private readonly apiUrl = 'http://your-api-url'; // Replace with your API endpoint

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getAdminMandates(filter: PagingFilter): Observable<PageResult<AdminMandateListDto[]>> {
    const params = this.buildParams(filter);
    return this.http.get<Response<PageResult<AdminMandateListDto[]>>>(`${this.apiUrl}/api/admin-mandates`, { params })
      .pipe(
        map(response => response.data)
      );
  }

  private buildParams(filter: PagingFilter): HttpParams {
    let params = new HttpParams();
    params = params.append('pageNumber', filter.pageNumber.toString());
    params = params.append('pageSize', filter.pageSize.toString());

    if (filter.searchQuery) {
      params = params.append('searchQuery', filter.searchQuery);
    }

    if (filter.sortBy) {
      params = params.append('sortBy', filter.sortBy);
      params = params.append('isSortAscending', filter.isSortAscending.toString());
    }

    if (filter.startDate && filter.endDate) {
      params = params.append('startDate', filter.startDate.toISOString());
      params = params.append('endDate', filter.endDate.toISOString());
    }

    return params;
  }
}
```

component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AdminMandateListDto, PagingFilter, PageResult } from './models'; // Import necessary models
import { AdminMandateService } from './admin-mandate.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-admin-mandate',
  templateUrl: './admin-mandate.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./admin-mandate.component.css']
})
export class AdminMandateComponent implements OnInit {
  adminMandates: AdminMandateListDto[];
  pageResult: PageResult<AdminMandateListDto[]>;
  filter: PagingFilter = {
    pageNumber: 1,
    pageSize: 10,
    searchQuery: '',
    sortBy: '',
    isSortAscending: true,
    startDate: null,
    endDate: null
  };

  constructor(private adminMandateService: AdminMandateService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getAdminMandates();
  }

  getAdminMandates() {
    this.adminMandateService.getAdminMandates(this.filter)
      .subscribe(result => {
        this.pageResult = result;
        this.adminMandates = result.pageItems;
      });
  }

  onPageChanged(pageNumber: number) {
    this.filter.pageNumber = pageNumber;
    this.getAdminMandates();
  }

  onPageSizeChanged(pageSize: number) {
    this.filter.pageSize = pageSize;
    this.getAdminMandates();
  }

  onSearch() {
    this.filter.pageNumber = 1;
    this.getAdminMandates();
  }

  onSort(sortBy: string) {
    if (this.filter.sortBy === sortBy) {
      this.filter.isSortAscending = !this.filter.isSortAscending;
    } else {
      this.filter.sortBy = sortBy;
      this.filter.isSortAscending = true;
    }
    this.getAdminMandates();
  }

  onDateRangeSelected(startDate: Date, endDate: Date) {
    this.filter.startDate = startDate;
    this.filter.endDate = endDate;
    this.getAdminMandates();
  }
}
```

component.html:

```html
<div>
  <h1>Admin Mandates</h1>

  <div>
    <label>Search:</label>
    <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="filter.searchQuery" (keyup.enter)="onSearch()">
    <button (click)="onSearch()">Search</button>
  </div>

  <div>
    <label>Sort By:</label>
    <select [(ngModel)]="filter.sortBy" (change)="onSort($event.target.value)">
      <option value="">None</option>
      <option value="id">ID</option>
      <option value="merchantId">Merchant ID</option>
      <!-- Add more sort options as per your requirements -->
    </select>
    <button (click)="onSort(filter.sortBy)">Toggle Sort Order</button>
  </div>

  <div>
    <label>Date Range:</label>
    <input type="date" [(ngModel)]="filter.startDate">
    <input type="date" [(ngModel)]="filter.endDate">
    <button (click)="onDateRangeSelected(filter.startDate, filter.endDate)">Apply</button>
  </div>

  <div>
    <button (click)="onPageChanged(pageResult.currentPage - 1)" [disabled]="pageResult.currentPage === 1">Previous</button>
    <span>{{ pageResult.currentPage }} / {{ pageResult.numberOfPages }}</span>
    <button (click)="onPageChanged(pageResult.currentPage + 1)" [disabled]="pageResult.currentPage === pageResult.numberOfPages">Next</button>
  </div>

  <div>
    <select [(ngModel)]="filter.pageSize" (change)="onPageSizeChanged($event.target.value)">
      <option value="10">10</option>
      <option value="20">20</option>
      <option value="50">50</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <div>
    <button (click)="onExportToExcel()">Export to Excel</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

How do I now re-write my component.ts, especially:

```
  getAdminMandates() {
    this.adminMandateService.getAdminMandates(this.filter)
      .subscribe(result => {
        this.pageResult = result;
        this.adminMandates = result.pageItems;
      });
  }
```

to tell the application that whenit is (click)="onExportToExcel()"

it should export, and when it's search query then it should perform that action based on the choice in the backend controller?

I mean passing this:

bool exportToExcel